# In Rails Admin, I need help to limit the number of rows in Dashboard for History_Index Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using Rails_admin together with Papertrail.

Because I inserted the "History_Index" action, in "config.actions", like below:

```
history_index do
 only PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL
end
#This is showing all modifications I'm doing in the models (more than 100 #lines). I need only to show the last 10, for example.
```

Now, the number of rows that are appearing in the Dashboard are at least 100.
Can I limit this number for, for example ONLY the last 10 records?

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

Someone helped me in a open issue in Github in Rails_Admin project.

Observation:
Instead of creating a new "dashboard" file, I inserted:

```
register_instance_option :auditing_versions_limit do
   25
end
```

inside /config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

Inside the "dashboard" action. Thus:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
config.actions do

     ... a lot of stuff...

    dashboard do
      register_instance_option :auditing_versions_limit do
        10
      end
    end                     
    ... a lot of other actions ...
  end
end
```